# MySQL - what does skip-locking in my.cnf do?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.0.67 on RHEL5 and basing my configuration on my-huge.cnf.

I can't find anything in the MySQL manual for the row 'skip-locking' which appears in the config file.

Should this be replaced with 'skip_external_locking' or should I just remove the row entirely as that is now a default.

[MySQL Manual for skip-external-locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-external-locking)

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/external-locking.html

quote:

> If you run multiple servers that use the same database directory (not recommended), each server must have external locking enabled.

It really just has to do with the dangers presented by multiple processes accessing the same data. In many DBMS situations you want to lock the table/row before performing an operation, and unlocking afterwards. This is to prevent possible data corruption.

Edit: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/news-4-0-3.html
Quote

> Renamed --skip-locking to --skip-external-locking.

Comment: Thanks - but that's skip_external_locking - I'd like to know if 'skip-locking' is the same thing, and if is necessary in the config file because it is already a default?

Comment: Thanks again, so to summarise - the 'skip-locking' row of the config file can be removed because a) it is out of date, the variable has been renamed. b) that behaviour is the default anyway

Answer (score 1):

An additional note for anyone who doesn't follow the link provided by @Jonathan Fingland :
[8.7.4. External Locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/external-locking.html)

This option only applies to MyISAM tables.

As Richard indicated, external locking is disabled by default. You need to enable external locking if you use `myisamchk` for write operations or if you use `myisampack` to pack tables.

From the docs:

> If you use myisamchk to perform table maintenance operations on MyISAM
>   tables, you must either ensure that the server is not running, or that
>   the server has external locking enabled so that it locks table files
>   as necessary to coordinate with myisamchk for access to the tables.
>   The same is true for use of myisampack to pack MyISAM tables.
>
> If you use myisamchk for write operations such as repairing or
>   optimizing tables, or if you use myisampack to pack tables, you must
>   always ensure that the mysqld server is not using the table. If you
>   don't stop mysqld, you should at least do a mysqladmin flush-tables
>   before you run myisamchk. Your tables may become corrupted if the
>   server and myisamchk access the tables simultaneously.