# MySQL 5.5 on Lion not working

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-lion

I've installed MySQL 5.5 via the disk image on Mac OS X 10.7. I've also added `/usr/local/mysql/bin` to my path in `.bash_profile`.

`which mysql` returns `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

However, I can't seem to get the server running, no matter whatever I try.

`mysql -u root` returns:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe` starts and then immediately stops the daemon:

```
120130 23:18:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Bryans-Macbook-Pro.local.err'.
120130 23:18:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
120130 23:18:59 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/Bryans-Macbook-Pro.local.pid ended
```

I feel that I have tried every possible solution that can be found, and I am out of ideas now. I've even tried installing an older version of MySQL (5.1) and got the same results and efforts invain.

**FURTHER INFORMATION**

Running `mysqld` results in:

```
$ mysqld
120209  0:02:23 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-5.5.20-osx10.6-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
120209  0:02:23 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120209  0:02:23 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120209  0:02:23 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120209  0:02:23 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120209  0:02:23 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120209  0:02:23 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120209  0:02:23 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120209  0:02:23 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120209  0:02:23 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120209  0:02:23 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
120209  0:02:23 [ERROR] Aborting

120209  0:02:23  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120209  0:02:24  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
120209  0:02:24 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

**UPDATE**

Well, I removed mysql completely from my system, re-installed an older version (5.1), and it is actually starting up now. However, I still can't run `rails server`. I get the following error:

```
/Users/bricker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Users/bricker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib (LoadError)
```

So, I've run this command:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib /opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

But still receive the error when attempting to start the 'rails server'.

**UPDATE 2**

Okay, final update: After everything, reinstalling mysql numerous times, seeing all these errors - it turns out that perhaps the original problem was a conflict between gems `mysql2-0.2.7` and `mysql2-0.3.11`. To ultimately fix the problem:

1. Removed all mysql-related files from my system (see bash script below)
2. Installed MySQL 5.1.61 (64-bit) from the Disk Image provided on the MySQL website
3. Ran the following lines:

`sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib /opt/local/lib/mysql5/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.16.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle`

`sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle`

1. ran `gem uninstall mysql2`, and selected the version `0.3.11` - the only version left on this RVM section is `mysql2-0.2.7`.

Now everything seems to be working! Thanks again for all the help.

**Bash script to remove mysql-related files from Mac OS X (10.6 & 10.7).**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/PreferencePanes/My*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
sudo rm -rf /var/db/receipts/com.mysql.*
echo "Done."
```

Copy into `remove-mysql.sh`, make it executable (`chmod +x remove-mysql.sh`), and run it.

Comment: Have you looked into the quoted error log, or the system console?

Comment: The error log that it mentions is empty, and I am not sure how to check the system console.

Comment: Applications > Utilities > Console

Comment: All it says in the system console is that I ran the command: `1/31/12 12:09:39.915 AM sudo:  bricker : TTY=ttys001 ; PWD=/private/tmp ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`

Comment: See, if this link helps: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/ Have you checked whether /tmp contains mysql.sock?

Comment: boy, do a `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/Bryans-Macbook-Pro.local.err`

Comment: How did you install mysql server? via homebrew/macport or via source?

Comment: Have any of these recommendations helped?  Where are you at on this issue?

Comment: @lqez Installed from disk image, via macports, via homebrew... all of them yielded the same results. Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: @AnishaKaul The file is there and has 777 permissions for group _mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Run `mysql_upgrade`
2. Remove `skip-locking` option from `my.cnf`: [MySQL - what does skip-locking in my.cnf do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943723/mysql-what-does-skip-locking-in-my-cnf-do)

If you cannot find `skip-locking` in your `my.cnf`, that means that MySQL loads it from path different to your expectations. Double-check that.

P.S. It seems that you upgraded your MySQL from some old version, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I am upgrading from an old version. I removed skip-locking from my.cnf, and I am now receiving the following error: `Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist`. I've found some possible solutions on Google, but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: What version are you upgrading from?  There's some very specific things you need to do when moving major revisions and sometimes small revisions.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/upgrading.html  Can you post up your old /etc/my.cnf and any changes the upgrade might have made to it?

Comment: Did you run `mysql_upgrade`? Obviously, during improvements in MySQL between version 5.0 and 5.5 there was added specific system tables that needs to be created. As a quick solution for you may be better to normally run MySQL 5.0, dump all databases using `mysqldump`, clean installation (remove everything about MySQL or move it somewhere), install new version and set up databases using `mysql -u <user> -p<password> < <yourdump.sql>`. In another way you must follow all the steps to ugrade 5.0->5.1->...->5.5... There was a lot of changes in structure and architect

Comment: Ohhh... If you upgraded from 4.x, dumping database may be only option for you not to have a lot of headache...

Comment: @Timur I am totally fine with completely wiping all of the data I have.

Comment: @bricker So, if you don't need data, than the simpliest way is to completely delete MySQL, data folder, etc, and install new version from scratch. Make a choice...

Comment: @Timur - I am accepting your answer because, even though it didn't directly answer my question, it is the answer that caused me to realize that I should reinstall mysql.

Comment: Also, I guess I might as well give you the bounty, since I'm not getting it back anyways.

Answer (score 3):

In one of the lines in the error log, this caught my attention

```
120209  0:02:23 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
```

[**I think `--skip-locking` is a pretty old option**](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/2439).

You might want to replace that in my.cnf with [**skip-external-locking**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-external-locking) instead

Since you removed `--skip-locking` go find datadir in my.cnf and make sure you are pointing that variables where the mysql data is located.

Comment: Removing the `--skip-locking` line did yield results, but now running `mysqld_safe` results in the error `Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds (to me) like you have a permissions issue.

Check the perms on the following directories:

> /usr/local/mysql/bin
>   /usr/local/mysql/data
>   /usr/local/mysql/include
>   /usr/local/mysql/lib
>   /usr/local/mysql/scripts
>   /usr/local/mysql/share
>   ...
>   /usr/local/mysql/*

They should all be read/write/excute for the mysql user and mysql group

Read more on install layout: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation-pkg.html#mysql-installation-layout-macosx

mysql_safe script: I think it might do a user switch to the "user" mysql.
Read more on that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html

Comment: All the files in /usr/local/mysql/ have been given 777 permissions and switched to group `_mysql`, but I still get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure your data directory is readable/writable by mysql.

Try to run `mysqld_safe --skip-locking &`

That should start the server in the background.  Then login with "mysql" .. it shouldn't ask for any credentials.

Check to see if you have any users defined within the user table on the mysql database.

You *may* have to manually add a user (as the grants system is bypassed above) using :

```
use mysql
insert into users <standard insert record stuff here>
```

When done, come out of the mysql client and do a `killall -s1 mysqld` .. you may need to do a `killall -s 15 mysqld` to get the backgrounded job to finish cleanly. Please dont do a `-9` on the poor old process.

Jobs/kill %% etc can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
```

Seems like you need to install it right and let it create the sock file needed

Comment: Did you install the MySQL Startup Item from the MySQL disk image? If you did, you should be able to run that line, and MySQL should also have started at boot time.

Comment: I've gotten mysql to start - now receiving a different error when attempting to run `rails server`.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `mysql_install_db` from your `/usr/local` directory. For more info, see [this blog post](http://blog.ryantremaine.com/2012/04/mysqld-table-mysqlplugin-doesnt-exist.html).